# SQLIte inserting null instead of the desired value

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

**Updated per commenter questions:**

I am trying to insert a value into a SQLite table, but when I fetch that value, it looks like null is getting inserted instead.

The call to insert the row and fetch/log all the existing rows above it is given as:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Deck deck = new Deck(mDeckNameText.getText().toString());
    dbHandler.addDeck(deck);

    List<Deck> allDecks = dbHandler.getAllDecks();
    Log.d("Get Decks", "Getting all decks");

    for (Deck one_deck: allDecks){
        int deck_id = one_deck.getDeckId();
        String deck_id_string = ""+deck_id;
        Log.d("ID: ", deck_id_string);

        String deck_name = one_deck.getDeckName();
        if (deck_name != null) {
            Log.d("Name: ", deck_name);
        }
        else {
            Log.d("Name: ", "null");
        }
    }
}
```

The addDeck method in to insert the row (which is in my database handler) is as follows:

```
void addDeck(Deck deck) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_DECK_NAME, deck.getDeckName());

    db.insert(TABLE_DECKS,null,values);
}
```

Where the Deck class is defined as:

```
public class Deck {

    int _deck_id;
    String _deck_name;

    public Deck(){
    }

    public Deck(String deck_name) {
        this._deck_name = deck_name;
    }

    public Deck(int deck_id, String deck_name) {
        this._deck_id = deck_id;
        this._deck_name = deck_name;
    }

    //get deck_id
    public int getDeckId(){
        return this._deck_id;
    }

    //set deck_id
    public void setDeckId(int deck_id){
        this._deck_id = deck_id;
    }

    //get deck name
    public String getDeckName(){
        return this._deck_name;
    }

    //set deck name
    public void setDeckName(String deck_name){
        this._deck_name = deck_name;
    }
}
```

The table that contains the decks is created in the following method:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_DECKS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_DECKS+"("
            +KEY_DECK_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+KEY_DECK_NAME
            +" TEXT"+")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_DECKS_TABLE);
}
```

The methods to fetch the decks are as follows:

```
//get single deck
public Deck getDeck(long deck_id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DECKS + " WHERE "
            + KEY_DECK_ID + " = " + deck_id;

    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c != null)
        c.moveToFirst();

    Deck deck = new Deck();
    deck.setDeckId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DECK_ID)));

    return deck;
}

//get all decks
public List<Deck> getAllDecks() {
    List<Deck> deck_list = new ArrayList<Deck>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DECKS;

    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Deck deck = new Deck();
            deck.setDeckId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DECK_ID))));

            // adding to decks
            deck_list.add(deck);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return deck_list;
}
```

The log output I get when I fetch the deck ids and deck names from the rows in my table looks something like this (after the third attempt at inserting a deck):
D/ID:﹕ 1
D/Name:﹕ null
D/ID:﹕ 2
D/Name:﹕ null
D/ID:﹕ 3
D/Name:﹕ null

Any idea why the name is coming back as null?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: where is the code you use to fetch data from sqlite? in your onclick you are instantiating a new object that has empty deckname

Comment: The deckname is not instantiated to mDeckNameText.getText().toString()?

Comment: I have also updated the question to include the code I use to fetch data from sqlite. Thanks again!

Comment: add  deck.setDeckNAme(c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DECK_NAME)))); in your getAlldecks method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a line in the fetch code:

```
deck.setDeckName(c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DECK_NAME))));
```

Add this in **getDeck** right before the **return** statement

I wrote from memory 
Hope it helps 
Please rate if yes

Comment: I can't vote because I don't have enough reputation points. When I do I will come back and vote it up! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, marking as answered is better than up vote